# Pessoal eu tenho um for que a cada volta mostrará um vídeo. Eu quero que os vídeos fiquem alinhados 3 X 3 na página. Como posso fazer isso?

Tags: css3, django

[image: Imagem]

Eu quero alinhar os vídeos que o laço vai exibir da seguinte forma, mas sem usar Bootstrap:

[]  []  []

[]  []  []

[]  []  []

Se fosse só Frontend eu conseguiria fazer esse alinhamento com CSS(FLEX-BOX) de boas, mas eu nn sei como fazer isso nesse for. Alguém me salva pf.

Comment: *"Se fosse só Frontend eu conseguiria fazer esse alinhamento"* mas aqui é só CSS, o que não consegue fazer? faça um CSS que coloque ele em flex ou inline-block e os tamanhos corretos, que não importa o for ou quantos elementos tem que eles vão ficar alinhados

Comment: Lembre de sempre enviar o código, não prints do código, isso ajuda a comunidade a de bugar o código, apesar de que como dito pelo Ricardo, ai é apenas CSS.
coloque uma div externa ao for, essa div com display flex, width 100% e justify-content space-between que ja vai ajudar..

Answer (score 1):

Coloca um container pai por fora do `loop` da `section class="mp4"` e coloca na section `{width: calc(100% / 3)}` por exemplo. Sendo que o container pai sim seria em `flex`.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.pai {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.mp4 {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  box-sizing: border-box;

  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<!-- container pai por fora do elemento do loop -->
<div class="pai">

  <!-- elemento do loop -->
  <section class="mp4">1</section>
  <!-- fim do loop -->

  <section class="mp4">2</section>
  <section class="mp4">3</section>
  <section class="mp4">4</section>
</div>
```